# Two links in Layout

Tags: layout, hyperlink, double

Can I do this in my Layout?

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css" + "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why don't you make it in two separate lines?

Comment: I need two links to two diffrent css, is it possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```